# If constructors should do no work, how about initialization of Views and ViewModels in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, constructor

There are a lot of books on OO best practices recommending constructors that do no real work. That is, you should have a "clean" constructor, so that you can always instantiate a new object in a unit test, for example, and extra work should be made elsewhere (usually in some `initialize()` method or such). Specifically, appearences of `new` keyword in constructors is somewhat frowned upon.

But, in WPF/MVVM, this is not always quite like it happens. This idiom is quite common, for example:

```
public SomeView : Window
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new SomeViewModel();  // or the XAML equivalent
}
```

I have been creating applications expecting everything to "assemble itself" when I start the application, but I wonder if it violates the "no work in constructor" principle somehow, and/or if I should take some precaution about it.

(So far, the most annoying thing (and quite common, indeed), is to have a `XamlParseException` when the ViewModel is instantiated in XAML and raises some error.)

Comment: can you use Load event as in Wndows Form load event

Comment: @EhsanSajjad indeed I used it sometimes, but wondering if it count as "work in the constructor" anyway?

Comment: The `Loaded` event is the appropriate place to do your initialisation work and is quite separate from the constructor. Putting code into the constructor can make the application UI freeze *before it has been displayed properly*, whereas even if your initialisation code is synchronous and causes the UI to freeze from the `Loaded` event, at least the UI will be visible first. Of course, it's better to use asynchronous code, so that the UI doesn't ever freeze. You should also use an Attached Property to access the `Loaded` event from the view model.

Comment: I never understood why it should be a big problem if an ui freezes for a split second and in contrast to that it should be completely ok that mandatory required data is displayed "a little" later. I like it if the ui displays "loading..." and is blocked until everything is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't `unit test` Views so I don't think setting `DataContext` is going be a problem or break any best practices.

Instead of "newing" ViewModel in View's constructor, I personally prefer setting it in XAML. You might consider getting your ViewModels from an `IoC` container. For example

```
using Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc;

public class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<RepositoryBase<Model>, ModelRepository>();
        SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    }

    public MainViewModel MainVM
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>(); }
    }
    ...
}

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    ...
    x:Class="Namespace.MainPage"
    DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainVM}"
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

And what comes to ViewModels, for example, there's really just a few ways to inject dependencies. That'll be constructor- or property injection. I don't think that count as "doing work", either, so just overload the default constructor and don't worry about "dem rules" :)

Consider the following ViewModel. Is it "doing work" ?

```
public class MainViewModel 
{
    // if feeling lazy, provide default dependencies
    public MainViewModel()
        :this(new ModelRepository()) 
    {}

    // attribute for IoC/dependency injection
    [PreferredConstructor]
    public MainViewModel(RepositoryBase<Model> modelRepository)
    {
        ModelRepository = modelRepository;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Initialize());
    }

    public RepositoryBase<Model> ModelRepository { get; set;}

    private async Task Initialize()
    {
        // Do stuff; populate properties for binding etc.
        var models = await ModelRepository.GetAllAsync();
        ...
    }
}
```

I think not.

It has default constructor and overload which work fine when running the application, given IoC is setup right, and it is also easy to test. In unit tests, just pass in the `mock` repository in constructor (or via property but constructor is more convenient).

For example

```
[TestClass]
public class MainViewModelTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        var models = new ... // collection
        var repository = new Mock<RepositoryBase<Model>>();
        repository.Setup(r => r.GetAllAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult(models));

        var viewModel = new MainViewModel(repository.Object); 

        // Assert stuff...
    }
}
```

---

> So you are implying that "new viewmodel in construction" is something
>   that should be avoided if possible, is that it? What about attaching
>   some initialization to the Loaded event?

I'm not implying anything. I just personally prefer using XAML because this leaves codebehind initially clean.

I'm not a huge fan of using View's events if it can be avoided. If event is bound to `Command` in ViewModel then it's OK.

Instead of waiting for `Loaded` event or such, I usually initialize the ViewModel as soon as it's constructed; get data from repository, populate  `ObservableCollection`s View is going to bind to, etc...  see example above.

What would be the case (that can't be avoided) that I first wait View to load and only after initialize it's DataContext?

Comment: So you are implying that "new viewmodel in construction" is something that _should_ be avoided if possible, is that it? What about attaching some initialization to the `Loaded` event?

Comment: Edited the answer, a little too long as a comment.

Comment: Interesting last question, it makes sense: Why should a view exist - and in the verge of being rendered - if its datacontext doesn't exist yet? Anyway, I think I was actually thinking about _ViewModel initialization_ when I wrote the question, so let's expand a bit: how do you initialize your viewmodel as soon as it's constructed? Doing work in the constructor? If not, how do you call the initialization method "automagically"? (I'm not being sarcastic, just want to know how).

Comment: Like in example above, e.g. have a new Task deal with it so UI thread is not blocked  `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Initialize());`